# Emacs terminal prompt

Tags: term

My main setup uses `zsh` and `prezto` on Mac OS with a custom prompt theme (I use `iTerm2` and not `Terminal.app`).

I was wondering what's the best way to have a similar experience with an Emacs terminal emulator.

I seems that the answer is easy: `M-x ansi-term` (or just `M-x term` ?)

However the prompt is not very nice as Emacs doesn't understand the special character my theme uses (some kind of fat arrow).

How could I fix this? Can I 'detect' in my `zshrc` file that I'm inside Emacs and change the prompt?

Comment: Do you have `(set-terminal-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)` in your init file?

Comment: I didn't but now I do and it didn't change.

Comment: You can use the `INSIDE_EMACS` environment variable.  The value varies contextually (it is different in a `M-x shell` buffer than it is in a `M-x term` buffer), so you can also make more granular decisions if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`M-x ansi-term` (and `M-x term` by the way) sets the `TERM` environment variable to `eterm-color`, so that's something you can use to adjust the prompt in you .zshrc

I have something similar in my `prezto` setup (although for `dumb` terminal, which is even more limited):

```
# Disable color and theme in dumb terminals.
if [[ "$TERM" == 'dumb' ]]; then
  zstyle ':prezto:*:*' color 'no'
  zstyle ':prezto:module:prompt' theme 'off'
fi
```

You might want something more subtle in your case !

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for. It seems also that prezto automatically switches the prompt off when the terminal is dumb.